# Angular2 rxjs sort (observable) list of objects by an observable field

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs, observable

I want to sort a list of things by an observable field, but can't wrap my head around observables to get this working. Has somebody an idea how to achieve this?

The initial situation is something like the following:

```ts
Thing[] things;

interface Thing {
  name: Observable<string>
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="const thing for things">
    {{thing.name | async}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since I obviously haven't described my problem properly: The field I want to sort the list of things on is an Observable, not a plain string. I want to keep the field updated via websockets so to detect the changes properly I have to use an Observable field on which I can subscribe.

Comment: What's the idea behind having name as an Observable<string>? I think you want to leave that property as a normal string

Comment: I want to use the field as an observable, since it's value may change at runtime.

Comment: Phosphoros, you are neither subscribing to the `name` or a `Thing`, but to the list of things (`Observable<Thing[]>`)

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's a real mistake. The abstraction of my usecase is wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying the question, Phosphoros. :)

Here's how you could do what you asked:

```ts
// Function to compare two objects by comparing their `unwrappedName` property.
const compareFn = (a, b) => {
  if (a.unwrappedName < b.unwrappedName)
    return -1;
  if (a.unwrappedName > b.unwrappedName)
    return 1;
  return 0;
};

// Array of Thing objects wrapped in an observable.
// NB. The `thing.name` property is itself an observable.
const thingsObs = Observable.from([
  { id: 1, name: Observable.of('foo') },
  { id: 2, name: Observable.of('bar') },
  { id: 3, name: Observable.of('jazz') }
]);

// Now transform and subscribe to the observable.
thingsObs

  // Unwrap `thing.name` for each object and store it under `thing.unwrappedName`.
  .mergeMap(thing =>
    thing.name.map(unwrappedName => Object.assign(thing, {unwrappedName: unwrappedName}))
  )

  // Gather all things in a SINGLE array to sort them.
  .toArray()

  // Sort the array of things by `unwrappedName`.
  .map(things => things.sort(compareFn))

  .subscribe();
```

Logging emitted values to the console will show an array of Thing objects sorted by their `unwrappedName` property:

```js
[
  { id: 2, name: ScalarObservable, unwrappedName: "bar" },
  { id: 1, name: ScalarObservable, unwrappedName: "foo" },
  { id: 3, name: ScalarObservable, unwrappedName: "jazz" }
]
```

Please let me know if you have questions about this code.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks! This example didn't worked though (without throwing an error!), because compareFn must be declared before usage.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll reorganize the code starting with the `compareFn` declaration.

Comment: @AngularChef   I am faced with a very similar issue, but my sorting must be the result of the user clicking a button to sort the data already on the page.  How would you sort this on a button click?

Answer (score 16):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have an object that looks like this:

```
Thing {
   name: string;
}
```

You then have want to have an Observable that holds on array of `Thing`:

```
things$: Observable<Thing[]>;
```

You then want to sort your things in the `thing array` by a property, in this case `name`. That could be done like this:

```
...

let sorted$: Observable<Thing[]> = things$.map(items => items.sort(this.sortByName))

...

sortByName(a,b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

...
```

And then finally, like **Toung Le** showed in his answer, change your template like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let thing of sorted$ | async">
    {{thing.name}} <!--No need async pipe here. -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the extensive answer, but the name field I want to sort on isnt a string, but an Observable<string>, since this field may be changed in the database and will then be updated automatically.

Comment: @Phosphoros, hmm, that still sounds weird to me. Can you maybe update your question to show us how the data you are working on looks?

Comment: @FredrikLundin, (noob here) where do you put the code that you are declaring the method variable `sorted$`?  In the `component.ts`?  I want to call that method using a button click `<button (click)="this.sorted$()">Sort</button>` (if that's possible written as you have it).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Observable.map`. For example:

```
Observable<Thing[]> things;
sortedThings$ = things.map(items => items.sort()) // Use your own sort function here.
```

In your template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let thing of sortedThings$ | async">
    {{thing.name}} <!--No need async pipe here. -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't helpful, since I'm interested in this nitty gritty detail, how to sort on an observable field.

Comment: @Phosphoros. Your comment is not very clear. To me it looks like Tuong Le has answered exactly the question that you asked. Be more specific if you think his answer doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @AngularFrance "I want to sort a list of things by an observable field […]" isn't this clear enough? The observable field to sort on is the problem.

Comment: Well, repeating the question verbatim doesn't make it any clearer. Also, keep in mind everyone on here is offering their time and knowledge to try to help you. If some of us don't understand the question as it is, it'll be more helpful to offer clarification even though it might already seem crystal clear to you.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!
Here's the link to docs on the sort function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Observable.map` then `sort()` with `localeCompare` which would look something like this :

```
.map(data => ({
        label: data.name
}))
.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty simple solution, once you understand how [`.pipe`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) works and which [Operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) are there.

If we convert all items to an array using [`toArray`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/toArray) operator and pipe the whole array as a single item to [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator, where we'll be able to sort it and then breaks out the array back.

```js
interface Thing {
  name: string;
}

const things: Observable<Thing>;

...

things
   .pipe(toArray())
   .pipe(mergeMap(_things => 
      _things.sort((a, b) => 
         a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      )
   ));

// OR

things.pipe(toArray(), mergeMap(_things => 
   _things.sort((a, b) => 
      a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
   )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` operator (play [with it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby)):

```
const $things = getThings();

$things.pipe(
    groupBy(thing => thing.id),
    mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(
        reduce((acc, cur) =>[...acc, cur], [])
    ))
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

[Groupby docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html).

Answer (score 0):

Changed the sort function with a filter function also made it work with rxjs 6.6.2

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ys7a9m?file=index.ts