# How to make ng bootstrap typeahead work for number

Tags: angular

I start to use typeahead from ng bootstrap and it work well for string and I try to make it work for number and didn't success. I see this post but the answer not work and was wrong.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364927/how-to-format-ng-bootstrap-typeahead-results-by-numerically-ascending)

This is the Methods that work with string:

```
return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
  map(term => (term === '' ? this.companies.map((company) => company.nameHebrew)
    : this.companies.map((company) => company.nameHebrew).filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
);
```

What I try to do:

```
return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
  map(term => (term === '' ? this.companies.map((company) => company.id)
    : this.companies.map((company: any) => company.id).filter(v => v.indexOf(term) > -1)).sort((a, b) => a - b)
);
```

Thanks Happy New Year

Answer (score 0):

I success to make it, I had to convert the number to string first, and then sort it.

Solution work:

```
return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? this.companies.map((company) => company.id)
        : this.companies.map((company: any) => company.id.toString()).filter(v =>
          v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).sort((a, b) => a - b))
    );
```