# How to filter with a variable amount of categories in each element with rxjs filter

Tags: typescript, filter, rxjs, ionic4

I am trying to implement a sorting feature in my ionic/angular app. The app displays vouchers from an API, each with different categories. I need to have support for multiple categories. I have found a way to do this, however it requires each voucher to have either 0 or 2 categories exactly to function. I want to be able to make it more flexible to support 0,1,2 category vouchers.

The way it is working currently is by filtering out vouchers with no categories first, then checking the array of categories if the current category is the array's index 0 or 1 which gives an index error if there is no second category.

```
      //Removing vouchers that have no category
      this.removeNoCats = from(this.searchvouchers).pipe(filter(item=> item.get_categories.length !== 0))

      this.removeNoCats.subscribe(res => console.log(res.name));

      //Filtering through vouchers with categories
      this.filteredList = from(this.removeNoCats)
      .pipe(filter((item:any) => item.get_categories[0].name === this.category || item.get_categories[1].name === this.category),toArray())
```

How can I make it so that it can handle a variable amount of categories?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203953/angular2-rxjs-sort-observable-list-of-objects-by-an-observable-field) for some good suggestions on how to sort a stream of data in rxjs.  As a first step, you may want to use the [groupBy](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/groupBy) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get_categories` is an array, you can just use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
.pipe(
  filter(item =>
    item.get_categories.some(category => category.name === this.category)
  )
)
```

This has the advantage of working for arrays of any size, not just 0 through 2.